# C++: Convert string to a vector<double>

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am relatively new to C++ and would like to convert char strings of numbers to a vector of doubles.  These strings will have different length, but their lengths will always be known.  For example:

I have a `char*` string called "myValue" which looks like this `"0.5 0.4 1 5"` and has a known length, `length=4`.

I would like to convert this string to a vector of doubles like this:

`vector<double> Param` and give me the following output:

```
Param[0]=0.5, Param[1]=0.4, Param[2]=1, Param[3]=5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).  We would store the string into the `stringstream` and then extract the `double` parts out of it with a while loop.

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::vector<double> data;
char numbers[] = "0.5 0.4 1 5";
ss << numbers;
double number;
while (ss >> number)
    data.push_back(number);
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2414a0ae4934c152)</kbd>

Since we are using standard container I would suggest using a `std::string` instead of a `char []` and then we could change

```
char numbers[] = "0.5 0.4 1 5";
```

To

```
std::string numbers = "0.5 0.4 1 5";
```

Comment: You can just write `std::stingstream ss("0.5 0.4  5")`