# How can Boost Program_Options handle vector of arrays?

Tags: c++, eigen, stdvector, boost-program-options, stdarray

In my program, I need to perform some transformations uing the Eigen library. As I am using a config file for the user to ajust some settings, I am searching for a way to integrate the transformations in this config file. I came up with the following code:

```
#include <boost\program_options.hpp>
#include <boost\log\trivial.hpp>
#include <Eigen\Geometry>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    std::vector<std::array<double, 16>> trans;

    try {
        po::options_description desc("Options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("help,h", "Produce help message")
            ("config,c", po::value<std::string>(&configPath), "Path of the config file.")
            ("trans", po::value<std::vector<std::array<double, 16>>>(&trans)->multitoken(), "Vector of 4D Transformation Matrix. Syntax: {x_11, ..., x_14, x_21, ..., x_24, ..., x_44}")
            ;

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << desc;
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

        std::ifstream configFile(configPath);
        po::store(po::parse_config_file(configFile, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "error: " << e.what();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    catch (...) {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "Exception of unknown type!";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    Eigen::Affine3d transAff(Eigen::Matrix4d(trans.data()).transpose());

    // Do some stuff
}
```

But unfortunately I am running in an error when building my solution. The error happens at the add_options line of the transform and says:

```
myDirectory\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\lexical_cast\detail\converter_lexical.hpp(243): error C2338: Target type is neither std::istream`able nor std::wistream`able
myDirectory\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\lexical_cast\detail\converter_lexical.hpp(270): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::deduce_target_char_impl<boost::detail::deduce_character_type_later<std::array<double,16>>>' being compiled
myDirectory\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\lexical_cast\detail\converter_lexical.hpp(407): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::deduce_target_char<Target>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Target=std::array<double,16>
        ]
myDirectory\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\lexical_cast\detail\converter_lexical.hpp(464): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::lexical_cast_stream_traits<Source,Target>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Source=src,
            Target=std::array<double,16>
        ]
myDirectory\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\lexical_cast\try_lexical_convert.hpp(196): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::lexical_converter_impl<Target,src>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Target=std::array<double,16>
        ]
myDirectory\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\lexical_cast.hpp(41): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool boost::conversion::detail::try_lexical_convert<Target,Source>(const Source &,Target &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Target=std::array<double,16>,
            Source=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
        ]
myDirectory\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\program_options\detail\value_semantic.hpp(92): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'Target boost::lexical_cast<T,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>(const Source &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Target=std::array<double,16>,
            T=std::array<double,16>,
            Source=std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
        ]
myDirectory\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\program_options\detail\value_semantic.hpp(149): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::program_options::validate<T,char>(boost::any &,const std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>> &,T *,long)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::array<double,16>,
            _Ty=std::string
        ]
myDirectory\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\program_options\detail\value_semantic.hpp(184): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::program_options::validate<std::array<double,16>,char>(boost::any &,const std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>> &,std::vector<std::array<double,16>,std::allocator<std::array<double,16>>> *,int)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::string
        ]
myDirectory\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\program_options\detail\value_semantic.hpp(177): note: while compiling class template member function 'void boost::program_options::typed_value<std::vector<std::array<double,16>,std::allocator<_Ty>>,char>::xparse(boost::any &,const std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> &) const'
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::array<double,16>
        ]
myDirectory\myProgram\src\myProgram.cpp(91): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::program_options::typed_value<std::vector<std::array<double,16>,std::allocator<_Ty>>,char>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::array<double,16>
        ]
```

I think the error is due to the fact that vectors of arrays are not supported the way I try to do it. Is there any way to accomplish that or even a smarter way of handling those transformations?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the question by myself, with some modifications. If someone else has the same problem, I hope I can help him with this answer.

### Arrays in C++

In a first step, I changed all my arrays to `std::vector` due to more functionality and because arrays are discouraged in many posts as for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap).

### Using `std::string` as temporary replacement for inner `std::vector`

Since vector in vector is a difficult task for program options (because multitoken just adds elements to a vector and can't differ between layers of vectors), I replaced the inner `std::vector` with a string, so the add_options is now

```
std::vector<std::string> trans;

try {
    po::options_description desc("Options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("help,h", "Produce help message")
        ("config,c", po::value<std::string>(&configPath), "Path of the config file.")
        ("trans", po::value<std::vector<std::string>>(&trans)->multitoken(), "Vector of 4D Transformation Matrix. Syntax: x_11 ... x_14 x_21 ... x_24 ... x_44")
        ;

    ...
```

### Conversion from `std::string` to `std::vector<double>`

Now we can convert the strings from the inputs to vectors of doubles, as they can be used to create `Eigen::Matrix` and `Eigen::Vector`. I got the idea from NathanOliver in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260501/c-convert-string-to-a-vectordouble), wich I use like that:

```
std::vector<double> str2vec(std::string str) {
    std::vector<double> out;
    std::stringstream ss(str);

    double tmpVal;
    while (ss >> tmpVal)
        out.push_back(tmpVal);

    return out;
}
```

### All together

At the end my code looks like that:

```
#include <boost\program_options.hpp>
#include <boost\log\trivial.hpp>
#include <Eigen\Geometry>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

std::vector<double> str2vec(std::string str) {
    std::vector<double> out;
    std::stringstream ss(str);

    double tmpVal;
    while (ss >> tmpVal)
        out.push_back(tmpVal);

    return out;
}

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> transVecStr;

    try {
        po::options_description desc("Options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("help,h", "Produce help message")
            ("config,c", po::value<std::string>(&configPath), "Path of the config file.")
            ("transVecStr", po::value<std::vector<std::string>>(&transVecStr)->multitoken(), "Vector of 4D Transformation Matrix. Syntax: x_11 ... x_14 x_21 ... x_24 ... x_44")
            ;

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << desc;
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

        std::ifstream configFile(configPath);
        po::store(po::parse_config_file(configFile, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "error: " << e.what();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    catch (...) {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "Exception of unknown type!";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::vector<Eigen::Affine3d> affineVec;
    for(int i = 0; i<transVecStr.size();i++){
        affineVec.emplace_back(Eigen::Matrix4d(str2vec(transVecStr[i]).data()).transpose());
    }

    // Do some stuff
}
```